# Getting function workspace variable values to base workspace

Tags: matlab

I need to run a script within my script and get all the varialbes and values from that script to the current script WITHOUT mixing the workspaces. I was though I could write a function that runs the script and returns everything I need, but I can't seem to make it work, below are my failed attampts. Please help..

fileName is the name of the script to run and TestCaseNum is a var that fileName depends on, that's why thats there

```
    function [a b]=runCalScript(fileName,testCaseNum)
    TestCase=0;
    TestCase=testCaseNum;
    %TestCase=str2num(TestCase);
    run(fileName)
    a=whos
    %whoValues=who;
    whosValues=whos;
    %fprintf('%s \n',fileName);
    save('myFile.mat')

    matObj = matfile('myFile.mat');
    fname=fieldnames(matObj); 
    matObj.(fname{1})

    %WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK??
%     for i=1:length(whosValues)
%        %temp=whoValues{i,1};
%         temp=evalin('base',whosValues(i).name) %base or caller options don't work!
%     end;



%     for i=1:size(s,1) 
%         evalin('base',s{i,1})
%     end;
```

Comment: Do you actually mean running a *script*, or a function? The two are quite distinct in MATLAB, and as far as I know, scripts share their workspace with the caller, I mean they don't have a workspace on their own. If you have a script, this could explain why you don't have a caller/base workspace: there is only a base as no function is called, only a script is run.

Comment: sorry, I also need to know the class.. uint16 and so on

Comment: Hey Andras, I have s script from which a call a function (the one show) which in turn runs a script and attempts to return that workspace to my base in the form of a array, that was my attempt at not mixing workspaces.. hope that makes sense

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but I added an answer based on my best guess. Please consider cleaning up your example to leave out unnecessary code and to fix typos in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have

1. a script, basically with the MATLAB base workspace
2. the function `runCalScript` called from this script, with workspace #2
3. a second script, called from the function, sharing workspace #2

Then the variables from your second script are also seen by the function. I think you could go along every variable of the function's workspace, like in your example, then use `assignin` to recreate those variables in the base (=caller) workspace. Like so:

```
function [a b]=runCalScript(fileName,testCaseNum)
    TestCase=testCaseNum;
    run(fileName);
    whosValues=whos;

    %this should work
    for i=1:length(whosValues)
       assignin('base',whosValues(i).name,eval(whosValues(i).name));
    end
```

If you have a variable in your function, say, `v`, with value `[1 3 5]`, the assignment at one point will say

```
assignin('base','v',[1 3 5]);
```

which I think is exactly what you need: it will evaluate to `v=[1 3 5];` in your base workspace.

To be more precise, this is exactly what you want to achieve. Are you sure you need this? Why not return your variables as the function's output parameters?

**Update**: you can add the value of each of your variables to the struct given by `whos` as a new field named `val` (for instance):

```
for i=1:length(whosValues)
       whosValues(i).val=eval(whosValues(i).name);
end
```

and then simply set `whosValues` to be an output parameter, declaring your function as

```
function [a b whosValues]=runCalScript(fileName,testCaseNum)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andras, yes I want to return the variables as the functions output params, sorry I wasn't clear. This mixes the workspaces, exaclty what I don't want, as mentioned in my original post. I need this function to return the sturcture produced by whos but also with the **values** of all the variables from whos added to the structure, which can only be done my evaluating the variable names like you did. And I need all that info sent back to the script that calls this function, but don't know how to do that. 

hope this is more clear, thanks again!

Comment: or return the whos sturuct and the coresponding values in two seperate vars as long as I can match them back in my original script im good.. thanks again.. really appreaciate your help... just trying to hack your example right now.

Comment: YEEESS!! you are the man Andras!.. thanks so much! this works exaclty like I want.